# Simple encryption - Sum of Hashes in C

Tags: c, algorithm, math, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

I am attempting to demonstrate a simple proof of concept with respect to a vulnerability in a piece of code in a game written in C.

Let's say that we want to validate a character login. The login is handled by the user choosing `n` items, (let's just assume `n=5` for now) from a graphical menu. The items are all medieval themed:

eg:

```
 _______________________________
|           |           |       |
| Bow       | Sword     | Staff |
|-----------|-----------|-------|
| Shield    | Potion    | Gold  |
|___________|___________|_______|
```

The user must click on each item, then choose a number for each item.

The validation algorithm then does the following:

1. Determines which items were selected
2. Drops each string to lowercase (ie: `Bow` becomes `bow`, etc)
3. Calculates a simple string hash for each string (ie: `bow => b=2, o=15, w=23, sum = (2+15+23=40)
4. Multiplies the hash by the value the user selected for the corresponding item; This new value is called the `key`
5. Sums together the `keys` for each of the selected items; this is the final validation hash
6. IMPORTANT: The validator will accept this hash, along with non-zero multiples of it (ie: if the final hash equals 1111, then 2222, 3333, 8888, etc are also valid).

So, for example, let's say I select:

```
Bow (1)
Sword (2)
Staff (10)
Shield (1)
Potion (6)
```

The algorithm drops each of these strings to lowercase, calculates their string hashes, multiplies that hash by the number selected for each string, then sums these keys together.

eg:

`Final_Validation_Hash = 1*HASH(Bow) + 2*HASH(Sword) + 10*HASH(Staff) + 1*HASH(Shield) + 6*HASH(Potion)`

By application of Euler's Method, I plan to demonstrate that these hashes are not unique, and want to devise a simple application to prove it.

in my case, for 5 items, I would essentially be trying to calculate:

`(B)(y) = (A_1)(x_1) +  (A_2)(x_2) + (A_3)(x_3) + (A_4)(x_4) + (A_5)(x_5)`

Where:

```
B is arbitrary
A_j are the selected coefficients/values for each string/category
x_j are the hash values for each string/category
y is the final validation hash (eg: 1111 above)
B,y,A_j,x_j are all discrete-valued, positive, and non-zero (ie: natural numbers)
```

Can someone either assist me in solving this problem or point me to a similar example (ie: code, worked out equations, etc)? I just need to solve the final step (ie: (B)(Y) = ...).

---

In the end, I wrote a recursive algorithm that goes `n` levels deep, then handles incrementing, testing, etc, for all remaining possible combinations. Not very efficient, but it works. I could provide it upon request (too large to post here).

Comment: Updated. Good point. Thanks. +1

Comment: Which parts do you have trouble with implementing?

Comment: Do you need to proof that the hashes generated in this way will not be unique for the strings selected?

Comment: The only part I can't figure out is the calculation of the sum itself. I tried matrix algebra, but it's not as simple as I thought, especially with the requirement that all coefficients are positive and non-zero (ie: non-trivial solution).

Comment: @phoxis: That is correct. I need to demonstrate that the hashes are non-unique, and that I can rapidly generate duplicate hashes.

Comment: Why do the `Bow` and `Shield` obtain the same number (in the parentheses) in your example?

Comment: @EitanT There is not reason in particular, the choices were arbitrary.

Comment: I don't understand: you pretty much outlined the steps you need to take to calculate the sum in your post already.  Which part of it do you have poblem with?

Comment: @Attila I don't fully understand an efficient means of calculating this sum, save for just testing every combination (ie: brute force). Since the number of items selected can also change, I'd have to hard-code in a set loop depth. I don't think I'm taking the right approach.

Comment: Technically, in order to prove that the algorithm does not produce a unique hash, you only need to prove the existance of a single counter-example - two different inputs that hash to the same value. You might be able to come up with one of those by hand (hint: look at letters that are common in different words; also, maybe start with a smaller instance of the problem - only two words/weights). Unless you are required to have a rigorous theoretical proof, that is...

Comment: What an appalling 'hash'. When you're done, make sure to print off your solution and use it to beat the author around the head for us.

Comment: I just did. For fun, I also produced solutions for increasingly large keyspaces. For the simplest example where it is limited to only 5 million possible hashes, we could produce 2800 duplicate valid hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that most users will select fairly small numbers for each item (after all "2" is easier for them to remember than "438483").

Given that constraint, brute force is probably actually reasonable.

Simply generating all possible input values for the 5 symbols plus a number say in the range of 1..99, computing the resulting hash, and counting (e.g. using a Dictionary) the number of distinct combinations that yield a given hash should give an empirical understanding of the hash distribution for the most probable input values.

From there I would look at how many distinct hash values were actually generated (out of the 2^32 possible hash values if the hash is an Int32), as well as look for the hash values that are generated with particular frequency (have a high count in the Dictionary).

Comment: I didn't think of it like that until Now. Thank you! +1; Accepted

Comment: :-)  I did something similar a while back looking for the rate of collision using CityHash with 100m real-life input values.  Sometimes, a sledge hammer is actually the most practical tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Well it may or may not be unique depending on the items on the menu `x_j`, the coefficients `A_j`, and the validation hash `y`, and the number of chosen items `n`.

For example, what happens if your validation hash is `1`? Then of everything would validate.

On the other hand if you have `n` be the total number of items, then there is only one possible hash which would be unique.

Of course these are extreme examples, but they illustrate the point. It depends on your parameters. There isn't a simple generic method for detecting whether or not hashes are unique except for brute force.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty trivial since the algorithm accepts non-zero multiples. If you multiply all the inputs by two you'll have a conflict:

```
Bow (1)
Sword (2)
Staff (10)
Shield (1)
Potion (6)

y = (A_1)(x_1) + (A_2)(x_2) + (A_3)(x_3) + (A_4)(x_4) + (A_5)(x_5)
```

Then multiply them by 2:

```
Bow (2)
Sword (4)
Staff (20)
Shield (2)
Potion (12)

2(A_1)(x_1) + 2(A_2)(x_2) + 2(A_3)(x_3) + 2(A_4)(x_4) + 2(A_5)(x_5)
= 2((A_1)(x_1) + (A_2)(x_2) + (A_3)(x_3) + (A_4)(x_4) + (A_5)(x_5))
= 2y
```

Comment: That's a bit of a trivial case; I need to change A_j and x_j.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is not a formal proof, but i have an idea.

Let the hashes of the different strings be `h_1`, `h_2`, ..., `h_n` the linear sum would be

`y = h_1 + h_2 + ... + h_n`

Once we have `y` we can always find `h_1'`, `h_2'`, ..., `h_n'` such that atleast for a pair of `i` and `j` `h_i != h_j'` in the series.

So we can have duplicate `h` values to get the final sum.

Again, because each `h` value is generated from the linear sum of some integers (representative values of characters), therefore a particular `h` value can be achieved by different linear sums, that is different strings.

The multiplier value can be adjusted. Also, even if the multiplier value is constant, that is the duplicate hash generator cannot select it, the `h` values multiplied with the multipliers can be modified such that the sum of multiplied keys remain constant.

Therefore we can generate one hash from many strings.

Answer (score 1):

Set all but the last coefficient to 1, so you get something of the form An*xn = r (mod y) and then use the extended Euclidean algorithm to find a solution, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_theorem#Solving_a_linear_congruence)